# 2-dimensional boolean indexing in Dask

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, dask

I want to 2-dimensional indexing using Dask. Here is an example of the task.

```
array1 = xr.DataArray([[1,3,4,7],[6,4,15,2]]).chunk(2)
array2 = xr.DataArray([[1,3,4,9],[1,4,3,2]]).chunk(2)
array1[array1 > 4] = array2[array1 > 4]
```

This returns an error - "IndexError: 2-dimensional boolean indexing is not supported."

Is there a workaround for doing this operation using Dask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out 'dask.array.where(array1 > 4, array2, array1)